# Купил мясо на буузу НА 500 руб или Купил мясо на буузу ЗА 500 руб . Все здесь в УУ говорят НА но никак не пойму почему

Tags: грамматика

Купил мясо на буузу НА 500 руб или Купил мясо на буузу ЗА 500 руб . Все здесь в УУ говорят НА но никак не пойму почему

Comment: *здесь в УУ* — это *там в Улан-Удэ*?

Comment: ага, в Улан Удэ

Comment: Буузы в УУ — просто уух!

Answer (score 5):

"Купить за X рублей" можно сказать, когда покупается какая-то фиксированная единица продукции. Например: купил кусок мяса за 500 рублей. Чуть хуже, но в разговорной речи также встречается "купил мясо за 500 рублей" в значении цены за 1 кг.

Если же делается покупка мяса на конкретное блюдо, то лучше употребить родительный падеж: **купил мяса**. И вот тут уже нельзя сказать "за 500 рублей", поскольку, вероятно, покупалась не фиксированная единица, а на развес (и, возможно, разных кусков/сортов) в общей сумме на 500 рублей.

Поэтому лучше сказать "купил на 500 рублей мяса на буузу" (я переставил слова местами, чтобы разнести подальше предлоги **на**). Соглашусь, что "купить мясо на 500 рублей" звучит плохо. Но прислушайтесь, может, люди говорят "мяса", а не "мясо" — тогда это правильно.

Answer (score 0):

Это из серии "оба варианта хуже".

Не знаю, что там в УУ происходит, объяснения "почему" дать не могу. Могу только порассуждать от правильности вариантов с точки зрения русского языка..

По поводу выбора предлога при "500 рублей" вам уже ответил grizzly, в целом с ним согласен, за исключением двух моментов. 1. Советы эти считаю рекомендательными, но не категоричными. 2. Главное, на мой взгляд, в форме "на 500 рублей" то, что основным показателем является не количество мяса, а сумма за него заплаченная. В не столь давние  времена такие формы были довольно популярны. В чайной, например, фраза "Подвари на копейку" означала порцию заварки стоимостью в одну копейку, которая добавлялась к уже имеющейся в чайнике заварке. Ну или до сих пор актуальная форма "[отложить] деньги на отдых, лечение".

Теперь по самой фразе вообще.
По моим представлениям Фраза более или менее корректно должна звучать так.
***Купил мясо для бууз на 500 рублей***. Или ***Купил мяса для бууз за 500 рублей***.
Второе, пожалуй предпочтительно, но это зависит от более широкого контекста.
"Бууза" - это, грубо говоря, пельмень. На буузу - это "на один пельмень". На пельмени - "на буузы". Но тут опять вылезает тот же предлог"на" в значении нормы, мерила. В таком контексте он выглядит сугубо разговорным, на гране просторечия. Более нормативным и стилистически нейтральным представляется "для бууз".

*Единственный недостаток: форма родительного падежа множественного числа для столь редкого и совсем не кодифицированного слова выглядит несвободной. В Монголии есть два различных обозначения этого блюда - **бууз** и **бо(ц)зи**. С ними родительный множественного затруднений не вызывает. Возможно в письменном тексте стоит немножко "передернуть" и обзначить бурятскую "буузу" одним из этих слов для удобочитаемости. Но если буряты будут настаивать именно на "буузы" (с буквой ы!) то такой прием в устной речи не пройдет.*

Comment: "В целом согласен", но рекомендация с точностью до наоборот? Или очепятки?

Comment: @Niemand я про ваши "наобороты" не в курсе. Если нетрудно, говорите более конкретно. Опечатки, что заметил, исправил.

Comment: спс
дело в том, что я слишком быстро написал сообщение, так что буузу вместо буузы

Comment: Мне сдается, что корректно так: купил мяса на 500 рублей, купил кусок мяса за 500 рублей. Купил мясо - вообще сомнительно.

Comment: Про наобороты не в курсе? Напомнить?


grizzly: *Купил кусок мяса за 500 рублей. Купил на 500 рублей мяса на буузу*
behemothus: **По поводу выбора предлога при "500 рублей" вам уже ответил grizzly, в целом с ним согласен. По моим представлениям Фраза более или менее корректно должна звучать так. Купил мясо для бууз на 500 рублей. Или Купил мяса для бууз за 500 рублей**

С точностью до наоборот?

Comment: @Niemand Простите?!

Comment: М_Г я не могу согласиться. Вам не нравится "мясо за" или "купил за"?!

Comment: @behemothus, сначала процитировал *grizzly*, потом **вас**. Противоречия в своих словах не замечаете? Сначала "в целом согласен", потом противоположная рекомендация.

Comment: @Niemand Вы правильно процитировали, не "наоборот". Это все, что я вижу. ))) *Сначала "в целом согласен", потом противоположная рекомендация* - Да, я в целом согласился, в первую очередь - с семантикой предлогов "на" и "за". Никаких "наоборотов". Выбор падежа - это как раз то, с чем я не согласился. Если бы не это, и писать ответ бы не стоило. Пл-моему, тут все достаточно прозрачно даже для таких блохоискателей как вы.

Comment: Так выбор предлога и падежа  - в этом и есть сущность вопроса.

Comment: *Так выбор предлога и падежа - в этом и есть сущность вопроса.* - или н6аоборот? )))

Comment: @user190655 Если это опечатка, то исправьте заголовок и текст вопроса.

Comment: behemothus, Mне не нравится "купил мясо" вместо "купил мяса". По-моему,  "купил мясо" нужно употреблять с большой осторожностью, когда говорят о мясе в целом (В областных центрах всего 36% опрошенных имели возможность купить мясо, колбасу в государственных магазинах. [Егор Гайдар. Гибель империи (2006)] или об известном мясе (Вижу два куска мяса. Я хочу купить это мясо) .

Comment: Если купил мяса, то "мяса на 500 рублей". А если купил за 500 рублей, то что-то определенное (кусок мяса, это мясо (этот кусок)) .